# Правильно ли сказуемое "высылает" согласуется с подлежащим?

Tags: согласование

Есть следующее предложение:

> На основании собственного опыта могу
> сказать, что 90 % партнеров из России
> прежде, чем наладить сотрудничество с
> моей фирмой, высылает на завод в
> Польшу своих сотрудников с целью
> ознакомления с процессом производства.

Вопрос: Правильно ли сказуемое "высылает" согласуется здесь с подлежащим, выраженным... количественным числительным? или словосочетанием? "90 % партнеров"? Может быть, нужно множественное число?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И то, и другое возможно. Если важно, что много, то ед. число "90% высылает", если имеются в виду партнёры как активные лица, то множ. - "90 % партнеров высылают". Я бы предпочла множественное.

Кроме того, запятая перед "прежде чем", а не в середине союза (если придаточное убрать, получится "...90 % партнеров из России **прежде** высылает на завод в Польшу своих сотрудников с целью ознакомления с процессом производства.) Союз в данном случае не расчленяется.

Получаем: "На основании собственного опыта могу сказать, что 90 % партнеров из России, прежде чем наладить сотрудничество с моей фирмой, высылают на завод в Польшу своих сотрудников с целью ознакомления с процессом производства.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: О людях лучше "направляют(-ет)" или с приставкой "при-" - если это на добровольной основе :) .

Comment: Согласна, направляет лучше

Answer (score 0):

Да, множественное число гораздо лучше.